# StateHasChanged not updating component

Tags: c#, blazor

I have two components, one is used to list all students and the   other shows details of a selected student.

Here are the parent components for both:

```
<p> Id of student @id </p>

<Students onStudentSelected="@getStudentId"> </Students>

<Student StudentId="@id"> </Student>


@code {
    private int id; 

    private void getStudentId (int e) {
        id = e;
        stateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Now here is the thing,the `<Students> </Students>` component works without issue, i.e. I can see list of students and when clicked on one, the id of the student is assigned to `id` and this is displayed inside the `<p></p>` tags.

But the `<Student> </Student>` component is not refreshing. If I manually give the Student component an id then I can see the Student details.

So, for some reason `stateHasChanged();` has no effect here.

---

If you want to see what these two components look like, it is as simple as:

**Students**

```
@foreach(var std in StudentsJSON) {
  <p @onclick="() => selectStudent(std.id)"> @std.name </p>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> onStudentSelected { get; set; }

    async Task selectStudent(int e){
        await onStudentSelected.InvokeAsync(e)
        // StateHasChanged(); tried here doesn't work
    }
}
```

**Student**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json 
@using System.Net.Http.Headers

@if(JsonResponseContent == null) {
    <p> No student found </p>
}else{
    
    @foreach(var st in JsonResponseContent) {
      <p> @st.age / @st.name / @st.subject </p>
    }
}


@code {
    [Parameter] public int id { get; set; }

    Student JsonResponseContent; 

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ...
        JsonResponseContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(ResponseContent);
    }    
    }
}
```

I don't know why the refresh is not working.

Comment: Where does the `Student` component call an URL for student details? Is it inside `OnAfterRenderAsync();`?

Comment: Can you try capturing the reference of a `Student` component with `@ref="StudentComponent"`. Then make function inside `Student` and inside it call `StateHasChanged()`. Call this function inside `getStudentId(int e)`?

Comment: @RandomSlav I updated the question to add what `Student` component contains

Comment: I don't understand the second comment, as I am not experienced with `@ref` yet

Comment: Move api call from `OnInitializedAsync()` to `OnParametersSetAsync();`.

Comment: @RandomSlav Thanks a lot bro, you did it. Can you answer showing why my code was wrong and I will accept+upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Student` component call api in `OnParametersSetAsync()` method

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync(){
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
   {
        ...
        JsonResponseContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student(ResponseContent);
    }    
    }
}
```

`OnInitializedAsync` gets call only once in component lifecycle while `OnParametersSetAsync` every time parameter value changes (in your example `id`). [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: "OnInitializedAsync gets call only once in component lifecycle..." that's not entirely true. "Blazor apps that prerender their content on the server call OnInitializedAsync twice:

Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page.
A second time when the browser renders the component."